# What is happening with the "Totally Not a Cow Level" buff?

Tags: diablo-iii

While playing today I got a new buff:

[image: Totally Not a Cow Level-buff]

It is pretty clear it has something to do with the blog [Debunking the cowspiracy](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19083832/).

But what does this event actually do?

Comment: My guess is just a community buff to say that there's a chance to get a portal to a cow level. Nothing more.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just shows the event being active, but I have no way to prove that.

Comment: From reading the [comments here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19083832?utm_content=external-sso&utm_medium=other&utm_source=App#comments), it sounds like there is a chance for getting an orange portal (which I believe is what @JonathanDrapeau is referring to) containing tons of gold and some loot.  Some say it's fun, but not a crazy amount of loot.  I'm about to go find out for myself!

Comment: @Chippies since as you point out there is no way of proving that i have changed the question to be about the event rather than the buff

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update:** With patch 2.3 it is now posible to open a portal to this area by placing a Bovine Bardiche in the Kanai's Cube.

There is a chance of running in to a special goblin like Cow called "Herald of the Queen".

[image: Herald to the Queen on Torment VI]

If you have sound on you will hear mooing when you get close and a cow icon will show up on your mini map.

[image: Killed it to fast to get a screen shot]

Killing this will open a portal to a place that dose not exist (zone name is "Not the cow level" when you get inside):

[image: Portal to a place that does not exist]

Inside you will find The Cow Queen:

[image: The cow Queen]

And Ghost of the Cow King that will start an event:

[image: Cow King Event]

The even rewards xp, gold and 4 cursed chests:

[image: 4 Cursed Chests]

Other than this the area is full of cow mobs, dead farmers that drops some gold, a lot of chests and a lot of shrines.

Some of the health globes spawn as T-Bones:

[image: T-Bone healthglobe]

The full map looked like his once I was done:

[image: Map of Not The cow Level]

Buff did not change while inside the level.

I have run in to one two time, once in act 1 and once in act 4, both times in zones related to a bounty.

Comment: I just ran into one in act 2 in a zone that did not have any bounty assigned to it (western sewers, level 2). I believe the little cow minion can spawn anywhere a goblin can spawn. My map also was different shape, so it must be randomly generated. The message from cow queen when I spoke to it was also different, so there's a fair bit of randomness to the whole thing it seems.

Comment: Actually, I noticed you have a Cow King, not Cow Queen. I didn't pay attention to who I was speaking to, but I definitely killed the Cow Queen, not King. If you fought the king instead then that's even more random stuff...

Comment: There is no cow level.

Comment: @Chippies You don't fight the King.  You fight the Queen.  But the King is also there with an event that spawns a bunch of cows to try and kill you.  Sort of like a cursed chest/shrine event, minus the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the cow with the loot that appears (i think) randomly. Kill it while it opens a portal to escape. Go through the portal to end up in the cow level.

After 2x a level with cows, I ended up in a sunny grassland with loads of rainbows, killing teddy bears, running flowers and unicorns... Not a lot of loot though...